# SVN commit error - code checked out to Windows XP drive mapped to an Ubuntu Samba share

Tags: windows, svn, samba, tortoise-svn, smb

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to commit changes to SVN that are on a mapped drive - the drive is mapped to a Samba share on a Ubuntu (9.04) server.

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image: TortoiseSVN Commit error]

I have full read and write permissions on the Samba share:

- I can modify the file
- I can clear out the whole directory and do a clean CheckOut from the repository

Here are the relevant settings in `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    security = user
    map to guest = bad user
    guest account = *******  (standard user)
    usershare allow guests = yes

[theshare]
    comment = Share Comment
    path = /var/www/theshare (permissions: drwxrwxrwx)
    browsable = yes
    read only = no
    guest only = yes
    guest ok = yes
```

I've searched Google but haven't had any joy picking the right search terms to get any suitable results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like repositories checked out onto mapped drives aren't recommended:

From http://old.nabble.com/Log-entry-missing-%27name%27-attribute-td25657118.html..

> The manuals explicitly warn against using network shares for working copies. Especially because of these kind of possible errors.

oh well!

---

**EDIT - RESOLVED!**

On further investigation, this looks like it could be a [bug with using a working copy located on the root of a drive](http://old.nabble.com/svn-1.6.x-regression:-svn-commit-damages-%27root-of-drive-working-copies%27-under-windows-td23105484.html)..

I moved the share up a level, and **re-mapped the drive so it contains a single directory, which holds the working copy *and commits now work!***

Hope that saves you some time  :o)